# Perl Getopt::Declare parameter action not invoked

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I use [`Getopt::Declare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Declare) in a script but invoking the script and passing `-get_ip "test"` doesn't do anything i.e. the script executes the "my" statements and getFirstAvailableIP doesn't get called.

```
use Getopt::Declare;
use lib "/home/vtsingaras/NicTool/client/lib/";
use NicToolServerAPI;
use strict;
use warnings;
#debug remove
use Data::Dumper;

#NicToolServer settings, edit
my $ntconf = {
    ntuser => 'censored',
    ntpass => 'censored',
    nthost => 'censored',
    ntport => 8082,
};

my ( $zone, $fqdn, $ip, $comment );

my $options_spec = q(+g[et_ip] <zone>   Get the first available IP from the provided reverse <zone>.
                        {getFirstAvailableIP($::zone);} 
+s[et_dns] <fqdn> <ip> <comment>    Create an A record for <fqdn> that points to <ip> and the associated PTR record.
{createFwdAndPtr($::fqdn, $::ip, $::comment);}  
    );
my $args = Getopt::Declare->new($options_spec);
#Setup NicTool
my $nt = new NicToolServerAPI;
$NicToolServerAPI::server_host   = $ntconf->{nthost};
$NicToolServerAPI::server_port   = $ntconf->{ntport};
$NicToolServerAPI::data_protocol = "soap";
#$NicToolServerAPI::use_https_authentication = 0;

sub nt_login {
    #Login to NicTool Server
    my $ntuser = $nt->send_request(
        action   => "login",
        username => $ntconf->{ntuser},
        password => $ntconf->{ntpass},
    );
    if ( $ntuser->{error_code} ) {
        print( "Unable to log in: " . $ntuser->{error_code} . " " . $ntuser->{error_msg} . "\n" );
        exit 1;
    } else {
        print( "Logged in as " . $ntuser->{first_name} . " " . $ntuser->{last_name} . "\n" );
    }
}

sub getFirstAvailableIP {
    my $fqdn = $_[0];
    print $fqdn;
    die "blah";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you specified **+** instead of **-** in `$options_spec` for `get_ip`.

Here is a self-contained runnable example which calls `getFirstAvailableIP`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Declare;

my $zone;

my $args = Getopt::Declare->new(<<'END_OPTS');
    #               tab
    #               ||||
    #               vvvv
    -g[et_ip] <zone>    Get the first available IP from the provided reverse <zone>.
        { getFirstAvailableIP($zone); }
END_OPTS

print "hello world\n";

exit;

sub getFirstAvailableIP {
    print "blah - @_\n";
}

__END__
```

And executed:

```
$ perl declare_test.pl -get_ip test
blah - test
hello world
```

Note that this module requires a `tab` character in its specification; this makes it difficult to copy'n'paste correctly.